# String is not writing as a timestamp to firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, datetime, google-cloud-firestore, fullcalendar

so I had the date string `Friday, April 15, 2022` and I converted it to `Thu Apr 14 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Irish Standard Time)` by string manipulation and now I'm writing it to firebase but it is saving as a string?

I am writing it to firebase like this:

```
const event = {
            Time: eventTime,
            start: newEventString,
            title: eventName,
            allDay: true
            
        }
        allEvents.push(event)

        const db = fire.firestore();
        db.collection("userEventsCal/"+currentUserUID+"/activities").add({event})
```

Because I am using reactFullCalendar, and the events isn't showing up in the calendar because of the date I think.

I am calling the user event info like below but when I use toDate() on the event start date it can't use it on a string because I know firebase returns a timestamp so I am not sure how to go about fixing this because none of the events are showing up in the react full calendar.

```
const getUserInfo2 = async () => {
  let currentUserUID = fire.auth().currentUser.uid

      console.log(currentUserUID)
      const qSnap = await fire
       .firestore()
       .collection('userEventsCal')
       .doc(currentUserUID)
       .collection("activities")
       .get()
    
    const data = []
    data = (qSnap.docs.map(d => ({ 
      id: d.id, 
      title: d.data().event.title, 
      start: d.data().event.start.toDate(),
      allDay: d.data().event.allDay,...d.data() })));
    
    
   
    setData([...data])

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must save a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) or [Firestore Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) object to save it as a timestamp in Firestore and not a string with a specific format:

```
const eventTime = "" // your date string

// TODO: convert the string to a Date

// const fireTimestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());

const eventTimeDate = new Date(eventTime)

// save this eventTimeDate in Firestore document
```

You might have to format your date string a bit to use `Date()` constructor and create a Date object. Checkout [Parsing a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5619202/13130697) for additional info.